# Excel nth smallest DISTINCT value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of values, the Small function gives me the ability to get the top 5 smallest values. but it doesnt take into account duplicates. I want to only see each value once. for example:

1 2 2 3 4 5

i want to output 1,2,3,4,5 not 1,2,2,3,4

I am putting the output into 5 different columns with the formula Small(A1:A20,[1-5])
but im not sure how to tell it to only look at each distinct value in the range

Answer (score 1):

If one has access to the dynamic array formulas (currently only available to office 365 insiders) one can just put this in the first cell and the results will spill across:

```
=SMALL(UNIQUE(A:A),SEQUENCE(,5))
```

[image]

---

Other wise we need to use some array formula in a specific manner.

We must have something besides a number in the cell directly preceding where we put the formula in the first cell.  So if I am putting the formula in C1, B1 must not contain one of the numbers as we need to refer to it.

Put this in C1:

```
=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B$1,$A$1:$A$20)=0,$A$1:$A$20),1)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy over 5 columns.

[image]

---

If one cannot leave the cell B1 without a number then we must get the array another way:

Put this array formula in the first cell:

```
=SMALL(INDEX($A:$A,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($A$1:$A$20,$A:$A,0)=ROW($A$1:$A$20),ROW($A$1:$A$20)*{1,1}))))),COLUMN(A:A))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy over 5 columns.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the nice dynamic formula (I guess you are an insider since recently?).

Comment: Yes, finally figured out how to get on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SMALL($A:$A,COUNTIF($A:$A,"<="&B1)+1)
```

Drag right...

Comment: I had a problem getting this to work in my excel but I did get it to work in google sheets. Thats where i want to use this so Good Job :)

Comment: Strange this didn't work in Excel, however do note that Google Sheets makes use of dynamic arrays which makes that @ScottCraner his answer might be applicable (maybe some slight adjustments?)

Comment: You formula even adding IFERROR, when you copied the C1 formula across right to S1, you will find 12345 will occur again in I1:M1, O1:S1…

Comment: @bosco_yip, yes it would, I do not see the problem with that however since the formula will skip a cell. Good to point out though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option and in single formula

Assume your data 1 2 2 3 4 5 put in A1:A6

B1, left blank

In C1, formula copied cross right until blank

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$A$20/($A$1:$A$20>B1),1)),"")
```

Edit : AGGREGATE is a function for Excel 2010 or above

Comment: I got this to work in excel but for some reason had problems getting it to work in my google spreadsheet... Good Answer though.